# How to correctly use all in dplyr's filter?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

Given simple code:

```
mtcars %>% 
  filter(am == 1 & cyl == 4)
```

the use of **`&`** returns:

```
   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
2 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
3 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
4 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
5 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
6 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
7 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
8 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

I would like to arrive at the same result using **`base::all`,** but the code:

```
mtcars %>% 
  filter(all(am == 1, cyl == 4))
```

does not produce desired results:

```
 [1] mpg  cyl  disp hp   drat wt   qsec vs   am   gear carb
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Hence my question, *how to correctly use **`all`** within dplyr's filter?*

---

#### Notes:

- dplyr version:

  ```
  >> packageVersion("dplyr")          
  [1] ‘0.7.4’
  ```
- base/R version:

  ```
  >> packageVersion("base")
  [1] ‘3.4.3’
  ```

Comment: you have to do this rowwise? `mtcars %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(all(am == 1, cyl == 4))`

Comment: @Jimbou It works, I would suggest that you make it an answer.

Comment: I don't like the rowwise approach so much as the data is grouped afterwards. Perhaps there is a better solution.

Comment: @Jimbou Fair point, it's definitely not intuitive.

Comment: I don't think `all` is meant to behave this way. `all` checks if "all" of the values in a vector fit a given set of conditions, as opposed to checking if *each* of the values in the vector fit the conditions. That's why it works rowwise.

Comment: @rosscova If you consider `identical(1 == 1 & 2 == 2, all(1 == 1, 2 == 2))` the answer is `TRUE`. IMHO, that should translate across the board; however, *within-filter* behaviour is different from what  one would naively expect when comparing `all` and `&` results.

Comment: That example doesn't quite translate to your problem. Here you're comparing "atomic" values, not vectors. Your example doesn't work for vectors, because `&` works differently from `all` in the case of vectors, which is effectively what you're working with in your problem.

Comment: @rosscova Valid point, I presume it would be better to look at `all(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE))` and `c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE) & c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)` the it becomes more obvious as `filter` should produce *per-row* `T/F`. TBH, you may provide that argument as an answer as it explains why it's not good idea and it also becomes clear what@Jimbou's solution does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`all` is slightly different from `&`, which is why it doesn't work as expected here. From the docs for `all`:

> Let ‘x’ denote the concatenation of all the logical vectors in
>   ‘...’ (after coercion), after removing ‘NA’s if requested by
>   ‘na.rm = TRUE’.
>
> The value returned is ‘TRUE’ if all of the values in ‘x’ are ‘TRUE’
>   (including if there are no values), and ‘FALSE’ if at least one of the
>   values in ‘x’ is ‘FALSE’.  Otherwise the value is ‘NA’ (which can only
>   occur if ‘na.rm = FALSE’ and ‘...’ contains no ‘FALSE’ values and at
>   least one ‘NA’ value).

Both `&` and `all` will take multiple logical vectors as input, but where `&` will return a new logical vector the same length as each of the inputs, `all` will always return a single logical value (`TRUE` if all values match the conditions, and `FALSE` if they don't).

`filter` needs a logical vector: `TRUE` to keep a row, or `FALSE` to discard it. A single logical value doesn't help. `filter` is then only able to either keep or discard *all* rows based on the single logical value returned by `all`.

Answer (score 3):

As an addon to the nice explanation of @rosscova you can try

```
mtcars %>% rowwise() %>% filter(all(am == 1, cyl == 4))
```

Comment: This is accurate, but I think a note should be included here that using `&`, and avoiding `rowwise` will be much more efficient. In my benchmarking on a 10,000 row data frame, this method takes over 300x as long to execute compared to using `&`. Not to mention the code is also more terse.